# Trouble highlighting in elasticsearch using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

After reading several sites (including elasticsearch's documentation) and experimenting around a lot, I'm having trouble getting highlights. I can do the basic keyword search, but it's clear I'm not grasping something. Here's my code.

Gems:

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
```

Controller:

```
class TermsController < ApplicationController

  def search
    @terms = Term.search(params[:query]).results
  end
end
```

Model:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 0 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :name, analyzer: 'spanish'
      indexes :gender, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :part_of_speech, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :definition
      indexes :etymology1
      indexes :etymology2
      indexes :uses
      indexes :romance_cognates
      indexes :notes1
      indexes :notes2
      indexes :quote1, analyzer: 'spanish'
      indexes :quote2, analyzer: 'spanish'
    end
  end

  def as_indexed_json(options = {})
    as_json(
      only: [:name, :gender, :part_of_speech, :definition, :etymology1, :etymology2, :uses, :romance_cognates, :notes1, :notes2, :quote1, :quote2]
    )
  end

  def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['name', 'definition', 'etymology1', 'etymology2', 'uses', 'romance_cognates', 'notes1', 'notes2', 'quote1', 'quote2']
          }
        },
        highlight: {
          tags_schema: 'styled',
          fields: {
            :'*' => {}
          }
        }
      }
    )
  end
end

# Delete the previous terms index in Elasticsearch
Term.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index: Term.index_name rescue nil

# Create the new index with the new mapping
Term.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create \
  index: Term.index_name,
  body: { settings: Term.settings.to_hash, mappings: Term.mappings.to_hash }

# Index all term records from the db to Elasticsearch
Term.import(force: true)
```

I also tried:

```
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['name', 'definition', 'etymology1', 'etymology2', 'uses', 'romance_cognates', 'notes1', 'notes2', 'quote1', 'quote2']
          }
        },
        highlight: {
          fields: {
            content: {'force_source': true}
          }
        }
      }
```

and

```
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['name', 'definition', 'etymology1', 'etymology2', 'uses', 'romance_cognates', 'notes1^5', 'notes2', 'quote1', 'quote2']
          }
        },
        highlight: {
          fields: {
            content: {type: 'plain'}
          }
        }
      }
```

and

```
  {
    query: {
      multi_match: {
        query: query,
        fields: ['name', 'definition', 'etymology1', 'etymology2', 'uses', 'romance_cognates', 'notes1^5', 'notes2', 'quote1', 'quote2']
      }
    },
    highlight: {
      pre_tags: ['<tag1>']
      post_tags: ['</tag1>']
      fields: {
        _all: {}
      }
    }
  }
```

...Along with many other attempts I can't remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the key that I was missing as [illustrated here](http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/) is that I needed the `try()` method in my view template. I'm sure there's a more concise way of writing this, but a sample of my view syntax looks like this:

```
<%= term.try(:highlight).try(:definition) ? term.highlight.definition[0].html_safe : term.definition.html_safe %>
<%= term.try(:highlight).try(:etymology1) ? term.highlight.etymology1[0].html_safe : term.etymology1.html_safe %>
```